# Discord Bot Changing status with repl.it?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I was wondering how it is possible to get a bot status to switch
please help me because I'm new to coding discord bots and I don't know much and when I google it it doesn't work for me.

This is my code:

```
import keep_alive
import discord, os
from discord.ext import commands
import typing
import asyncio
import random

prefix="cs!"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

def replaceSpaces(string): 
  string = string.strip() 
  i = len(string) 
  space_count = string.count(' ') 
  new_length = i + space_count * 2
  if new_length > 1000: 
    return -1
  index = new_length - 1
  string = list(string)  
  for f in range(i - 2, new_length - 2): 
    string.append('0')  
  for j in range(i - 1, 0, -1): 
    if string[j] == ' ': 
      string[index] = '0'
      string[index - 1] = '2'
      string[index - 2] = '%'
      index = index - 3
    else: 
      string[index] = string[j] 
      index -= 1
  return ''.join(string)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="cs!help || made with <3 by Spoon#7194"))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    servers = len(client.guilds)
    members = 0
    for guild in client.guilds:
        members += guild.member_count - 1

    await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(
        type = discord.ActivityType.watching,
        name = f'cs!help | {servers} Server {members} Member'
    ))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  
  msg = message.content.lower()
  
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  
  elif msg.startswith("cs!hello"):
    await message.channel.send(f"hello, {message.author}!")
  
  elif msg.startswith("cs!help"):
    await message.channel.send(f"commands: cs!hello, cs!replsearch <query>, cs!twitch <query>, cs!youtube <query>, cs!google <query>")
  
  elif msg.startswith("cs!replsearch "):
    resultr = msg.split('cs!replsearch ', 1)
    if resultr[-1] == "":
      await message.channel.send("Error :face_with_raised_eyebrow:, no query given")

  elif msg.startswith("cs!replsearch"):
    await message.channel.send("Error :face_with_raised_eyebrow:, no query given")
  
  elif msg.startswith("cs!twitch "):
    resultt = msg.split('cs!twitch ', 1)
    if resultt[-1] == "":
      await message.channel.send("Error :face_with_raised_eyebrow:, no query given")
    else:
      await message.channel.send(f"https://twitch.tv/search?term={replaceSpaces(resultt[-1])}")

  elif msg.startswith("cs!twitch"):
    await message.channel.send("Error :face_with_raised_eyebrow:, no query given")

  elif msg.startswith("cs!youtube "):
    resulty = msg.split('cs!youtube ', 1)
    if resulty[-1] == "":
      await message.channel.send("Error :face_with_raised_eyebrow:, no query given")
    else:
      await message.channel.send(f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={replaceSpaces(resulty[-1])}")

  elif msg.startswith("cs!youtube"):
    await message.channel.send("Error :face_with_raised_eyebrow:, no query given")

  elif msg.startswith("cs!google "):
    result = msg.split('cs!google ', 1)
    if result[-1] == "":
      await message.channel.send("Error :face_with_raised_eyebrow:, no query given")
    else:
      await message.channel.send(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={replaceSpaces(result[-1])}")

  elif msg.startswith("cs!google"):
    await message.channel.send("Error :face_with_raised_eyebrow:, no query given")
  
  elif msg.startswith("cs!"):
    await message.channel.send("Error :face_with_raised_eyebrow:, not a valid command")

#server.server()@bot.command()
#async def token
  #embed=discord.Embed(title="Help", description="description here")
  #embed.add_field(name="Moderation commands", value="your commands here", inline=False)
  #embed.add_field(name="Fun Commands", value="your commands here", inline=False)
  #embed.set_footer(text="footer text")
  #await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    keep_alive.keep_alive()
client.run('{I deleted this part here}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
const status = "YOURSTATUS"
client.user.setActivity(status)
```

Also Try that :)

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Status every x seconds

```py
@discord.ext.tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def change_p():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    statuses = [f"{len(client.guilds)} Servers with {len(client.users)} Users!", "You Talk!",
                "The Epic Server!"]
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=choice(statuses)))

change_p.start()
```